# How to create a custom ColorEffect

Tags: java, android, camera, effects

I simply want to know how could i create a custom ColorEffect.
As we can set some effects like

```
EFFECT_AQUA
EFFECT_BLACKBOARD
EFFECT_MONO
EFFECT_NEGATIVE
EFFECT_NONE
EFFECT_POSTERIZE
EFFECT_SEPIA
EFFECT_SOLARIZE
EFFECT_WHITEBOARD
```

I want to create my own  Color effect.

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_AQUA); //like EFFECT_REDDISH 
camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

Comment: ColorMatrix explained (VB NET): http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3772/ColorMatrix-Basics-Simple-Image-Color-Adjustment. Some more about ColorMatrix: http://docs.rainmeter.net/tips/colormatrix-guide. About ColorMAtrices (C#): http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/Transformations0512192005050129AM/Transformations05.aspx. You can derive the matrices from these examples to apply them in your own collection of color effects. Also you can get introduced to ColorMatrices.

Comment: DerGolem can you please explain me  p = 0xff & yuvByte[i]; a and 0xff000000 | nongreen << 16 | green << 8 | nongreen;

Comment: and then can I setColorEffect(MyColorEffect.GREEN); like this

Comment: Unclear... now I'm going out for a couple of hours. Please, in the meanwhile, recollect your ideas and clarify more.

Comment: Frank N.Stein how he can set the value to setColorEffect(string) where it needs a string value.