# How to do effective coding in Camera PreviewCallback

Tags: android, bitmap, camera, rgb

I have to create grey Scale camera live Preview. It is working fine. But i want to make the code faster.

```
private android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback previewCallback = new android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback()
{
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte abyte0[] , Camera camera)
    {
        Size size = cameraParams.getPreviewSize();

        int[] rgbData = YuvUtils.decodeGreyscale(abyte0, size.width, size.height);

        Bitmap bitmapung = Bitmap.createBitmap(rgbData, size.width, size.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Bitmap bitmapToSet = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapung, 0, 0, widthPreview, heightPreview, matrix, true);

        MyActivity.View.setBitmapToDraw(bitmapToSet);
};
```

1. As i am creating `Bitmap object twice`.Can i do this job with one
   `bitmap Object`.
2. where (on which method like onResume or onCreate) should i getCamera
   Size(means width and height once). So  that i don't need to set it for each `callback`.
3. And I know i should use `AsyncTask` to do it. I will do it after
   solving my current issue.

**EDIT**

I can create bitmap while getting `Camera Size(width,height)`. Then single instance of bitmap is associated to my Class. but i have to call `setPixels` for it.

```
bitmapung.setPixels(rgbData, offset, stride, x, y, size.width, size.height);
```

What should I set the values of Stride ,offset and x,y. And also explain them plz.

Also have a look on these questions also

[**Create custom Color Effect**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29672679/how-to-create-a-custom-coloreffect)

[**Add thermal effect to yuvImage**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29645950/how-can-i-add-thermal-effect-to-yuv-image)

Comment: To achieve grayscale preview, it may be enough to setup camera parameters with [`setColorEffect(Camera.parameters.EFFECT_MONO)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setColorEffect(java.lang.String)).

Comment: If you want more control, check *[Android: how to display camera preview with callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350230/android-how-to-display-camera-preview-with-callback)* - actually, the question there is more informative than the attempts to answer it.